Closed form expression for real differentiable functions whose n-th derivatives are themselves
Let $n$ be a positive integer, and consider the differential equation $D^n(f)=f$, where the $D^n$ represents the $n$-fold composition of the derivative operator. In the complex number system, that equation is easy to solve. However, I want a closed-form solution for the real number system. The main reason I am asking this, is because, to give a specific example, the trigonometric functions sine and cosine are their own $4$-th derivatives, but, unlike in the complex case, they do not seem to be expressible in terms of real exponential functions.

Why can’t you take the real and imaginary parts of the complex solutions to get the real solutions?

You get a polynomial in terms of exponential terms, $\sin$-terms and $\cos$-terms. What is your problem?

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Since the coefficients of all terms of your differential equation are real, it's always possible to write its general complex solution in a form which will be real when you choose the arbitrary constants in the expression for the solution to be real.
If $\ r_j\ed e^\frac{2\pi ij}{n}, j=0,1,\dots, n-1\ $ are the complex $\ n^\text{th}\ $ roots of unity, then the general solution of your differential equation is
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}A_je^{r_jx}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}A_je^{e^\frac{2\pi ij}{n}x}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}A_je^{x\cos\frac{2\pi j}{n}}e^{ix\sin\frac{2\pi j}{n}}\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
If $\ n\ $ is odd, \eqref{1} can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
&A_0e^x+\sum_\limits{j=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}e^{x\cos\frac{2\pi j}{n}}\left(A_j e^{ix\sin\frac{2\pi j}{n}}+A_{n-j}e^{-ix\sin\frac{2\pi j}{n}}\right)\\
=&A_0e^x\\
&+\sum_\limits{j=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}e^{x\cos\frac{2\pi j}{n}}\left(B_j \cos\left(x\sin\frac{2\pi j}{n}\right)+C_j\sin\left(x\sin\frac{2\pi j}{n}\right)\right)\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ B_j\ed A_j+iA_{n-j}\ $ and $\ C_j\ed A_j-iA_{n-j}\ ,$ and if $\ n\ $ is even, it can likewise be rewritten as
\begin{align}
A_0e^x&+A_\frac{n}{2}e^{-x}\\
&+\sum_\limits{j=1}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}e^{x\cos\frac{2\pi j}{n}}\left(B_j \cos\left(x\sin\frac{2\pi j}{n}\right)+C_j\sin\left(x\sin\frac{2\pi j}{n}\right)\right)\ .
\end{align}
Now if you choose $\ A_0,B_j,C_j\ $ and $\ A_\frac{n}{2}\ $(when $\ n\ $ is even) all to be real, then the final two expressions above will be real-valued functions whenever $\ x\ $ is a real variable.
